# Android lazy data binding possible?

Tags: android, lazy-initialization, android-databinding

One of the coolest features of the Android data binding support is that it also generates fields for View with IDs set. This tidies up the codebase as no field or `findViewById()` calls are necessary.

But the problem is that the binding instance can only be retrieved via the `bind()` call which tends to schedule binding. This is bad when the data is being received asynchronously and commonly the `NullPointerException` gets thrown.

Can the binding instance with View fields be retrieved minus the actual data binding process?

Stack-trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
         at com.app.android.databinding.ActivityRestaurantDetailsBinding.executeBindings(ActivityRestaurantDetailsBinding.java:381)
         at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:350)
         at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$6.run(ViewDataBinding.java:167)
         at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding$5.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewDataBinding.java:137)
         at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14525)
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't seem to make sense,  data binding will ignore null variables thus no null pointer should be thrown, that is, i believe, one of its most promoted features. If you need to modify variables after async calls etc you can just use `dataBinding.executePendingBindings()`

From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#variables)

> The generated binding class will have a setter and getter for each of the described variables. The variables will take the default Java values until the setter is called — null for reference types, 0 for int, false for boolean, etc.

and

> Generated data binding code automatically checks for nulls and avoid null pointer exceptions. For example, in the expression @{user.name}, if user is null, user.name will be assigned its default value (null). If you were referencing user.age, where age is an int, then it would default to 0.

Comment: I expected the same too. Upon checking the generated code, there were many null checks in place, but it wasn't true for this boolean type. Does this sound like a bug?

Comment: Have the same for 
`android:text="@{DateFormatter.format(item.orderDate)}"`. This results in a NPE cause of invoking `DateFormatter.format(null)`.

Comment: After having used databinding over the past few months there does seem to still be a lot of problems with null checking which is very disappointing. The most prominent cause of which being boolean types as @razzledazzle said

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with `java.lang.Boolean`. Solved by using primitive `boolean` type instead.

```
<variable
    name="var"
    type="boolean" />
```